# how to concat values from same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i wanna concatenate two values from the same column in that column here is my csv file :

```
Date,Region,TemperatureMax,TemperatureMin,PrecipitationMax,PrecipitationMin
01/01/2016,Champagne Ardenne,12,6,2.5,0.3
02/01/2016,Champagne Ardenne,13,9,3.9,0.6
03/01/2016,Champagne Ardenne,14,7,22.5,12.5
01/01/2016,Bourgogne,9,5,0.1,0
02/01/2016,Bourgogne,11,8,16.3,4.2
03/01/2016,Bourgogne,10,5,12.2,6.3
01/01/2016,Pays de la Loire,12,6,2.5,0.3
02/01/2016,Pays de la Loire,13,9,3.9,0.6
03/01/2016,Pays de la Loire,14,7,22.5,12.5
```

i want to have **Bourgogne Champagne Ardenne** instead of having them separated and calculate the average of **TemperatureMax**, **TemperatureMin**, **PrecipitationMax**, **PrecipitationMin**:

```
01/01/2016,Bourgogne Champagne Ardenne,10.5,5.5,1.3,0.15
02/01/2016,Bourgogne Champagne Ardenne,12,8.5,10.1,2.4
03/01/2016,Bourgogne Champagne Ardenne,12,6,17.35,9.4
01/01/2016,Pays de la Loire,12,6,2.5,0.3
02/01/2016,Pays de la Loire,13,9,3.9,0.6
03/01/2016,Pays de la Loire,14,7,22.5,12.5
```

Comment: How would you know that Bourgogne comes first, and Champagne Ardenne second? Or do you have only these two in your dataset?

Comment: @IanS you can base on date

Comment: But groupby + concatenate could return `Champagne Ardenne Bourgogne`, would that be correct?

Comment: @lanS i have other values in my dataset and i want to have exactly `Bourgogne Champagne Ardenne` because i wanna join it with other dataset that contain `Bourgogne Champagne Ardenne`

Comment: Then you'll have to be more specific about how to do the grouping. Add other regions to your example, and explain how they should be grouped.

Comment: @lanS done. but i dont care about order whether i have  `Bourgogne Champagne Ardenne` then  `Pays de la Loire`  or reverse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More general solution is first [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `dict` and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + aggregate [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
d = {'Champagne Ardenne':'Bourgogne Champagne Ardenne',
     'Bourgogne':'Bourgogne Champagne Ardenne'}

df['Region'] = df['Region'].replace(d)

df1 = df.groupby(['Date', 'Region'], as_index=False, sort=False).mean()
print (df1)
         Date                       Region  TemperatureMax  TemperatureMin  \
0  01/01/2016  Bourgogne Champagne Ardenne            10.5             5.5   
1  02/01/2016  Bourgogne Champagne Ardenne            12.0             8.5   
2  03/01/2016  Bourgogne Champagne Ardenne            12.0             6.0   
3  01/01/2016             Pays de la Loire            12.0             6.0   
4  02/01/2016             Pays de la Loire            13.0             9.0   
5  03/01/2016             Pays de la Loire            14.0             7.0   

   PrecipitationMax  PrecipitationMin  
0              1.30              0.15  
1             10.10              2.40  
2             17.35              9.40  
3              2.50              0.30  
4              3.90              0.60  
5             22.50             12.50
```

Comment: Glad can help you!

Answer (score 1):

Use groupby's `agg` method:

```
df.groupby('Date').agg({
    'Region': lambda g: g.sort_values().str.cat(sep=' '),
    'TemperatureMax': 'mean',
    'TemperatureMin': 'mean',
    'PrecipitationMax': 'mean',
    'PrecipitationMin': 'mean'
})
```

Note that this concatenates regions by alphabetical order.